# Accessibility Service crashes and cannot restart

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am testing t[his tutorial implementing an Accessibility Service](http://umeshisran4android.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-readparse-ussd-messages.html) to catch some text on a USSD menu.

It works well the first time I compile and launch the app using Android Studio in debugging mode:

I can see this line in the debugger:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
```

And right after I call a USSD menu I can see the content of the response message in the debugger as expected.

However if I disconnect the phone and just after try again the same app without any modification, the Accessibility Service does not seem to work or even to launch, as I cannot even see this Log.d line in the debugger

```
Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
```

I have tried the following unit tests:

**1. If I try to deinstall the app and recompile again,** it still does not work.

**2. If I deinstall the app, reboot the phone, and recompile again,** it works again until the next time I unplug and plug again the USB cable to run a new debug from Android Studio.

**3. If I just rename the Accessibility Service using the refactor option of Android Studio (adding a 2 after the name for instance),** it works again until the next time I unplug and plug again the USB cable to run a new debug from Android Studio.

It seems the Accessibility Service gets stuck or crashes somewhere when I unplug the USB cable and the app is unable to restart it the next time. I can also see the following error messages in the console which makes me think this is the problem:

```
((latest content captured from the USSD popup))
--- the USB cable is unplugged and plugged again ---
03-22 21:43:04.931 5774-5774/com.myapp D/UssdCatcher3: onAccessibilityEvent
03-22 21:43:04.932 5774-5774/com.myapp D/UssdCatcher3: com.myapp.MainActivity
03-22 21:43:12.023 845-1950/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp/.UssdCatcher3 in 1000ms
03-22 21:43:13.033 845-858/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 10243:com.myapp/u0a54 for service com.myapp/.UssdCatcher3
03-22 21:43:16.488 845-858/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp/.UssdCatcher3 in 1000ms
03-22 21:43:16.490 845-858/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{cb2cd91 u0 com.myapp/.UssdCatcher3}
03-22 21:43:55.225 10882-10882/? W/dex2oat: Compilation of java.lang.Object com.myapp.UssdCatcher3.access$super(com.myapp.UssdCatcher3, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 109.013ms
```

This is very weird, any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: Do you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I too have the same problem on my application, my solution is to invite the user to restart his phone when my application fails to establish communication with the accessibility service.